# C# Enforcing all TestMethods have an Owner attribute?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, continuous-integration, integration-testing, mstest

C# What ways can you enforce all TestMethod have an Owner attribute.

There are more than 50 projects and I want to ensure that, when a new project or test cases are added, owners of the tests are included in the program. Below is a sample of current code that users are not adding Owners for test methods.

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task Sometask()
{
    
}
```

However, I would want it to be consistent in all tests and projects like below.

```
[TestMethod]
[Owner(TestOwners.OwnerName)]
public async Task Sometask()
{
    
}
```

Also, since this is an MSTest running in VS, is there a way this can be enforced on the CI pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

Code analyzers have the best fit for your case ([microsoft article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/code-analyzers)). Here is the recipe:

1. Write a rule with `error` severity that looking for all usages of `Test method` attribute and then checking that all these usages have `Owner` attribute. This rule will produce error for every method that don't have `Owner` attribute and each one will be highlighted by IDE. The project build will be failing until the errors are fixed
2. Distribute your rule as a nuget package or visual studio extension
3. Make sure that every project has a dependency (can be transitive) with the package or every developer is using the vs extension

Actually I have the same rule in my company. Here is the source code - [NoTestWithoutOwnerRule](https://github.com/mindbox-cloud/Mindbox.Analyzers/blob/ad3b013b82993062fad0f339a18f5fa73aedbb0c/Mindbox.Analyzers/Rules/NoTestWithoutOwnerRule.cs#L9). We distribute it as a nuget package. And we also have a project template for creating new projects. This template has dependency with the package, so all new projects have the rule out of the box